# preload image directory

Tags: jquery, preload

I want to preload a directory with images.

So far i am using this Code:

preload.php

```
    <?php
function listImages($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..' && strstr($ff, '.png') || strstr($ff, '.jpg') || strstr($ff, '.gif') || strstr($ff, '.jpeg')){
            echo '"images/'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            echo '", ';
        }
    }
}
echo '[ ';
listImages('images');
echo ']';
// output: ["image1.png", "image2.png"] etc.
?>
```

footer.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // put contents of all_images.php file into variable 'images'

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  async: false,
  cache: false,
  url: "./preload.php",
  data: "getid=true",
  success: function(data){
  images=data;
  }
});

    // The variable 'images' now contains string of file names
    // needed to be preloaded.
    $.fn.preload = function() {
        this.each(function(){
            $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        });
    }


</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(images).preload();
</script>
```

But it doesnt seem to work. In Firebug i get `uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:`

If i paste all of my links instead of "images" `$(images).preload();`
I does`nt get an error, but my images are also not loaded.

any help is appreciated as im sitting here the whole day trying to figure it out.

UPDATE #1

so, now im doing it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("./preload.php?getid=true", function(data) {
    var images = [];
    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
      images[i] = new Image().src=val;`

        $.fn.preload = function() {
            this.each(function(){
                $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
            });
        }
        $(images).preload();
    });
  });
});
```

No error so far, but the images still dont show up in "Network" Tab of firebug.

Comment: Run it through [JSON encoder](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and use JSON to get it.

Comment: Try adding `dataType: 'json'` to your AJAX settings.

Comment: with dataType: 'json' i get `ReferenceError: images is not defined`

Comment: Your `$(document).ready(function(){ $(images).preload();` is not correct either

Comment: you have a backtick in your code after val;. Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 3):

Several issues

try [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("./preload.php?getid=true", function(data) {
    var images = [];
    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
      images[i] = new Image().src=val;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: with this i get: `ReferenceError: images is not defined`